# Change a value and Know if it changes in one line

Tags: c++, performance, expression

Below I am trying to **compare a value with itself after an operation**, and **I want to return it only if it changes**. I tried the code below, but I couldn't declare a variable in the middle of an expression. Is there a way to do this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
        if (ray[i] != (int a{ray[i] & (1u << 5)})) //THIS DOES NOT COMPILE
                return a;
```

Note that the reason I am asking this is for **efficiency** so that I won't have to **evaluate** the expression **twice** as below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
        if (ray[i] != (ray[i] & (1u << 5))
                return (ray[i] & (1u << 5); //EVALUATING THE EXPRESSION TWICE
```

Is there a way I could make an operation and know whether it changes the value of the first token? (This would also solve the problem)

Comment: Does it really have to be on one line? If you had `a` declared somewhere, I think your first example would work.

Comment: Indeed, the real problem here is the habit of not using brackets :)

Comment: What type is `ray[i]`?    More significantly, can it ever be negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, realize that unless `ray` has been qualified as `volatile` (or something like `atomic` to assure changes from another thread are visible), chances are pretty good that none of this is going to work at all--the compiler will assume that two reads from the same location without an intervening write will always produce identical results, and only read it once (then use it twice from the same register).

Assuming it is `volatile` or `atomic` (or otherwise thread-visible), I'd probably do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
    int first = ray[i];
    int second = ray[i] & (1U << 5);
    if (second != first)
        return second;
}
```

Assuming a halfway decent compiler, I'd expect `first` and `second` to be placed in registers, so overhead would be extremely minimal.

Answer (score 0):

this might help:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    if (ray[i] != 32 && ray[i] != 0)
            return (ray[i] & (1u << 5));
```

the if portion in your code will only be executed if `ray[i] is not equal to (ray[i] & (1u << 5))`, so first let's see when will `ray[i]` equal `(ray[i] & (1u << 5))`:
   Since the result of `(ray[i] & (1u << 5))` will either be 0 or 32 depending upon whether the 6th bit from the right in `ray[i]` is 0 or 1 respectively.
   So, I changed the if condition to `ray[i] != 32 && ray[i] != 0`, i.e. if the number on which the operation(bit operation and all) is being performed on is not 32 and is not 0, then only we pass the if condition check as was in your code.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I get what you did. However, the amount of operations still remains at 3 (i.e. no real gain). Also, it is a bit too specific to this case (my actual code contained `ray[i] & ~(1ULL << (move.init-1)`, which cannot be resolved like this. Thanks for your constructive thoughts, though!